# EF6 How to avoid creating tables for entities managed by another DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have below structure of classes:

1. SecurityLayer.Domain dll

   - User class and some other classes
   - Has a nuget package for this
2. SecurityLayer.Data dll

   - SecurityDbContext class (which inherits from DbContext and manages User related entities
   - Has a nuget package for this

Now I build another product which uses two packages above. And I have below structure

3. MyProduct.Data dll has a **ProductDbContext** to manage entities from **MyProduct.Domain dll**

The problem is when I use **Add-Migration on MyProduct.Data project**, EF generates a migration to create **ALL** entities from both MyProduct.Domain and SecurityLayer.Domain

I know that EF6 support multiple DbContext in a single database, but it does not work for me. Can we do something to let **EF avoid entities in SecurityLayer.Domain**? Any advice is much appreciate. Tks a lot!

Comment: Why not just edit the migration code after it's created to remove the bits that are note needed?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG but maybe it will be recreated on a later migration, do you think so?

Comment: No it won't. Migrations store the state of the database in a table called `__MigrationHistory`. One of those columns is actually a zipped up EDMX file. Each migration uses that to determine what has changed since the previous migration.

Comment: I concur with DavidG; we also generate migrations for each context and then edit them by hand to remove statements that concern a different context.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for your answers, it works for me also.

Comment: @hazjack OK, I'll add an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create your initial migration and remove the bits from it that are not relevant. Subsequent migrations will not pick up the existing tables due to the way EF works.

Migrations actually store the state of the database in a table called `__MigrationHistory`. One of those columns contains a zipped up EDMX file. You can extract the content as a blob, save it as a `.zip` file and see for yourself. Each migration uses that to determine what has changed since the previous migration.